# cookie in React JS (save/load)

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I am new to using cookies in React JS and I have a question regarding my code below.

```
console.log(this.state.datasets);
cookie.save('datasets', this.state.datasets, { path: '/' , 'maxAge': 100000});
var myArray = cookie.load('datasets')
console.log(myArray);
```

`this.state.datasets` is an array full of elements and went I initially print the array to the console, I am able to see the data.
However when I try printing out `myArray` I get an empty array. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: are you using any library?

Comment: yes, im sorry I should have included that. I'm using react-cookies

Answer (score 1):

You can save only strings as cookies. To save an array you'll have to somehow convert it into a string. If you have an array of objects you can store it by converting it into string by `JSON.stringify`.

For example

```
let colors = [
{
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
},
{
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
},
{
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
}]

let x = JSON.stringify(colors)
```

The value x will be a string which you can save to cookies.

And to retrieve it you can convert it back to an array of objects by using `JSON.parse`.

Something like

```
var myArray = cookie.load('datasets')
let obj =  JSON.parse(myArray)
```

`obj` will be the original object